# JQGrid Edit Form does not get focus on submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid, mvcjqgrid

I have started to use JQGrid with version 4.6 since last few days. I have used jqgrid data form to insert and update data of the grid. In the form I have used several text-boxes. I get focus to next text-box by pressing tab key as usual. This works fine. But when last textbox is reached and press tab button, the focus should be transfer to the submit button as it is the next element in the form. But it doesn't. I have also observe this behavior on jqgrid demo site. It would be much better if focus is shifted to the submit button when tab key is pressed from the last element of the edit form of JQGrid.

Please help me out on this.

you can check the behaviour on http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html and go to "New in version 3.5" -> Form Navigation.

Thanks & Regards,

Kartik Jajal

Comment: _"New in version 3.5"_....4.6 is available.

Comment: Its link where you can see the demo of the behavior.